# Creating two datasource with Spring

Tags: java, spring, jndi, persistence-unit

I'm trying to add two data sources in my Spring project, however, I'm getting this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ajaxController': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: entityManagerFactory,entityManagerFactoryDataGathering
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:357)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:835)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: entityManagerFactory,entityManagerFactoryDataGathering
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:572)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:531)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:697)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:670)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354)
    ... 22 more
```

Here is the relevant part of my `dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="benDS" jndi-name="jdbc/ben"
    expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<jee:jndi-lookup id="benDS_data_gathering"
    jndi-name="jdbc/ben_data_gathering" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="benDS" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="ben" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ben.*" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactoryDataGathering"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="benDS_data_gathering" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="ben_data_gathering" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ben.*" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />

<!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManagerDataGathering" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryDataGathering" />
</bean>
```

Here is my `UserDAO.java`

```
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION, unitName = "ben")
@Qualifier(value = "entityManagerFactory")
private EntityManager em;

@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION, unitName = "ben_data_gathering")
@Qualifier(value = "entityManagerFactoryDataGathering")
private EntityManager em1;
```

In Tomcat, here is my `context.xml`

```
<Resource name="jdbc/ben" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="-1" maxIdle="-1" maxWait="-1" autoReconnect="true"
    username="example" password="example" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    spring.datasource.testOnBorrow="true"
    spring.datasource.validationQuery="SELECT 1"
    url="example" />

<Resource name="jdbc/ben_data_gathering" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="-1" maxIdle="-1" maxWait="-1" autoReconnect="true"
    username="example" password="example" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    spring.datasource.testOnBorrow="true"
    spring.datasource.validationQuery="SELECT 1"
    url="example" />
```

And lastly, my `persistence.xml`:

```
<persistence-unit name="ben" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:/comp/env/jdbc/ben</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="20" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
            value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes"
            value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="ben_data_gathering" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:/comp/env/jdbc/ben_data_gathering</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="20" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
            value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes"
            value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I've been searching around SO for help and I couldn't get any progress. How am I able to correctly add a second data source? I was able to do it with just one just fine.

Comment: Can you also post the code of ajaxController and nested object need to wired inside it? We may need to trace it from the root of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Error happened while creation of bean 'ajaxController' and Not while creation of UserDAO . Have you wired EntityManager in ajaxController ?!

```
Error creating bean with name 'ajaxController'
```

Comment: Ha, funny thing. I have two versions of my project in the same workplace. I deleted the EntityManager on the wrong version so that's why it was getting errors...

Comment: So yes I did, but in the wrong project. I'm giving you +1 so you can get privileges to comment on posts faster ;)